# What options are available for a gnome2 feel in 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, menu

I am a desktop user and like the idea of an organized drop down menu. I don't care about themes, colors, and all that jazz. I just want an organized drop down menu, and a taskbar on the bottom with favorites and currently used applications. Based on what I have seen so far the options for a menu while still using gnome are:

- install gnome-session-flashback
- use extensions to modify gnome3 (ex: Arc menu)
- use Ubuntu Mate

For the first time Flashback is giving me a hard time. I don't like the "global" menu in Gnome3, and I don't like extensions. Ubuntu Mate is using gnome2, which is old, and I don't want to invest  time only to find out why gnome3 was needed.Sorry to be so negative. I guess I don't like change... comes with age :-)

Am I missing any other options to use gnome with a gnome2 type menu? What options am I overlooking?

Comment: While MATE is based on an older Gnome, it has had continued development. So, it's not like it's missing anything important. If anything, it would probably be easier to use MATE to get the usability/features you seem to be asking for. It's change, but it's easily surmounted change. There's also LXQt (see the newest versions of Lubuntu) and it has a familiar layout with the bits and bobs where you'd expect them to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNOME FlashBack shares the same illness as GNOME Shell. They break user habits which existed for years.

So you have to install MATE desktop by

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

and enjoy its Traditional panel layout

[image: MATE with Traditional panel layout]

with flexibility and usage of modern technologies like GTK3.

Also you can enable Plank dock on any side of the screen. Adding application launchers to any MATE panel is also possible. So, it's your desktop and only you decide how it will look.